# Enumerate DataFields in Excel Pivot Table with Powershell Core

Tags: powershell, excel-2016

Using powershell 7.1.3, I am able to load a spreadsheet and enumerate worksheets for example and I can find a pivot table on a sheet and echo it's name.  This is a pivot table that is conected to the local data model of the workbook and has many DataFields, which I can enumerate in VBA.

After loading the workbook, I successfully load the pivot table from a worksheet into a variable. I then access the DataFileds member and try to enumerate it's members but, I can only see these members...

`$testPivot.PivotFields() | Get-Member -Force`

In PowerShell 7.1.3 the array is not unwrapped
[image]

When I do the same thing in Windows Powershell 5.1, the array is unwrapped...
[image]

The behaviour in 7.1.3 for

`$testPivot.PivotFields() | Get-Member -Force`

is exactly the same as

`write-output -NoEnumerate $testPivot.DataFields() | Get-Member -Force`

in 5.1

How do I get the array to unwrap in 7.1.3?

Comment: It looks like you're getting a totally different object type. The v7 image shows a `Count` property like an array does, so could you have loaded multiple pivot tables? Try either `$testPivot[0].PivotFields()` or `$testPivot.PivotFields()[0]` to double-check.

Comment: @user19702 Yes, you are right! In 5.1, `$testPivot.DataFields()` returns an array of objecys but, in 7.1.3, it returns the array object and that is the diference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something quick you can do to let your code work in both versions is to check if the result is an array via:

```
$pivotfields = $testPivot.PivotFields()
  
if ($pivotfields -is [System.Array]) {
    # either pick the first one, or iterate through with foreach:
    $pivotfields[0]
    $pivotfields | Foreach { <# do stuff #> }
} 
else { 
  # proceed normally
}
```

Comment: Yep, that will work.  Thanks!  This looks like a bug in the excel object model (or inconsistency at least). Some of the collections are unwrapped in the normal way, like the `Workbook.Sheets` collection but some are not.